# error get certificate let's encrypt laravel forge on subdomain

Tags: laravel, dns, subdomain, laravel-forge

hello to the whole community, I can't understand why it doesn't let me get the ssl certificate via forge.. have any of you ever experienced this type of error? thank you so much community..

```
2023-10-26 07:40:34 URL:https://forge-certificates.laravel.com/le/1953529/2144174/ecdsa?env=production [4737] -> "letsencrypt_script1698306033" [1]
Cloning into 'letsencrypt1698306034'...
ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result: ["type"]  "http-01"
["status"]  "invalid"
["error","type"]    "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns"
["error","detail"]  "DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for example.com - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning"
["error","status"]  400
["error"]   {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns","detail":"DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for example.com - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning","status":400}
["url"] "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/277549912336/wpn4EQ"
["token"]   "2u0S3snX1Cqr03NyQUSSxOwM1p-tkyz-APT-fSZoGH8"
["validationRecord",0,"url"]    "http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/2u0S3snX1Cqr03NyQUSSxOwM1p-tkyz-APT-fSZoGH8"
["validationRecord",0,"hostname"]   "example.com"
["validationRecord",0,"port"]   "80"
["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved",0]    "ip...."
["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved"]  ["ip...."]
["validationRecord",0,"addressUsed"]    "ip..."
["validationRecord",0]  {"url":"http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/2u0S3snX1Cqr03NyQUSSxOwM1p-tkyz-APT-fSZoGH8","hostname":"example.com","port":"80","addressesResolved":["ip..."],"addressUsed":"ip..."}
["validationRecord"]    [{"url":"http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/2u0S3snX1Cqr03NyQUSSxOwM1p-tkyz-APT-fSZoGH8","hostname":"example.com","port":"80","addressesResolved":["64.227.64.195"],"addressUsed":"64.227.64.195"}]
["validated"]   "2023-10-26T07:40:44Z")
```